# New bone in armature doesn't move in animation after export into unity

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, unity

I rigged model in Mixamo and then I used this armature to animate my model.

Now I had to add bone to my armature but I don't get it how to do it.  I has three different situations with this.

1. When I add bone (in *Edit mode*) do my armature it generate sepetraret armature with that bone an several other IK and bones form my base armature
2. In second time in stick to my base armature but it doesn't show in my rig form so i can't animate this.
3. In the end I create bone which stick to my base armature and I can animate it and it work well (even I was happy it's work) but after I export this to Unity this new bone  doesn't move, though Unity sees that bone.

So what I can do to move this bone in unity ?

View from Blender

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEpOb3LuzE8dYUgiobYBjG4IsOzBhDzt/view?usp=sharing

Unity https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXoPNw6oUMYVOhPvan-96LLDOwg3NjHe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was in Unity, if you use a humanoid rig it doesn't show extra bones in animators so in Unity you should active these bones manualy.

Here is the answer  https://forum.unity.com/threads/humanoid-rigs-and-extra-bones.360979/